# Tailwind CSS not displaying using Create React App

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, tailwind-css, postcss

I created a simple test react app and followed all of the steps from the official tailwind website: "https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app". Here are the relevant files:

SampleComponent.js:

```
import React from 'react';

const SampleComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div className="bg-blue-500 p-4">
      <h1 className="text-white font-bold">This is a sample component using Tailwind CSS</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SampleComponent;
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import SampleComponent from './SampleComponent';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-200 min-h-screen">
      <SampleComponent />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

index.css:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

craco.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    style: {
      postcss: {
        plugins: [
          require('tailwindcss'),
          require('autoprefixer'),
        ],
      },
    },
  }
```

tailwind.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  purge: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', './public/index.html'],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^7.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.8",
    "postcss": "^8.4.27",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.17"
  }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of inspecting the element:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2wJi.png)

However, every time I try running `npm run start`, the Tailwind CSS is not being displayed.

I tried other possible solutions I found, such as running `npm install react-scripts@latest` and `npm install postcss@latest` as well as deleting `npm_modules` and `package-lock.json` and rerunning `npm install`, but to no avail.

Comment: I get some errors with the code given [in a new project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-femsap?file=src%2Findex.js) – perhaps you've missed some things out?

Comment: @Wongjn Interesting, I do not get those errors when running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation may be for an older version of `react-scripts`/`create-react-app`. Consider removing the `style.postcss.plugins` key from `craco.config.js` or indeed removing `@craco/craco` altogether, since v5 of `react-scripts`/`create-react-app` supports Tailwind out of the box.

See your project working in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-76785122-wcd954?file=%2Fpackage.json%3A1%2C1).

As an aside, [Tailwind recommends more modern build systems](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app):

> **Create React App does not support custom PostCSS configurations and is incompatible with many important tools in the PostCSS ecosystem, like `postcss-import`**.
>
> We **highly recommend** using [Vite](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite), [Parcel](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/parcel), [Next.js](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs), or [Remix](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/remix) instead of Create React App.

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate on "Consider removing the `style.postcss.plugins` key from `craco.config.js` or indeed removing `@craco/craco` altogether"? (i.e. should I move the `style.postcss.plugins` key to another file?)

Comment: Consider removing the `style.postcss.plugins` key from `craco.config.js`. The file should export an empty object. Check the linked CodeSandbox for an example.

Answer (score 0):

try adding
content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
in tailwind.config.js

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work.